# Is there a Ruby Cucumber test hook for at_start?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Is there a Ruby Cucumber test hook for `at_start`?   I tried **at_start** and it didn't work.

I have something like this in `support/hooks.rb` and I want to print a single global message before any of the tests start:

```
Before do
  print '.'
end

at_exit do
  puts ''
  puts 'All Cucumber tests finished.'
end
```

It seems like if they have an `at_exit` hook, they should have a `before-start` hook as well right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some documentation for "global hooks" at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks

You don't need to wrap it in any special method such as `Before` or `at_exit`. You just execute the code at the root level in any file contained in the `features/support` directory, such as `env.rb`. To copy and paste the example they've given:

```
# these following lines are executed at the root scope, 
# accomplishing the same thing that an "at_start" block might. 
my_heavy_object = HeavyObject.new
my_heavy_object.do_it

# other hooks can be defined in the same file
at_exit do
  my_heavy_object.undo_it
end
```

They also give an example of how to write a `Before` block that gets executed only once. Basically you have this block exit if some global variable is defined. The first time the block is run, the global variable is defined which prevents it from being executed multiple times. See the "Running a Before hook only once" section on that page I linked.